# In a linked hash map <integer,class object>. how can I modify equals and hash code to display values?

Tags: java

```
public class Event extends Framework  {


    Event e;
    public LinkedHashMap<Integer, Event_para> Lhm;

    void addVertex(int arrival_time,int mappers_req,int mappers_location,int reducers_req,int reducers_location,int link_capacity,float demand_capacity,int deadline) {

        Lhm.put(Framework.id, new Event_para(arrival_time,mappers_req,mappers_location,reducers_req,reducers_location,link_capacity,demand_capacity,deadline));

    }
    public  Event() {
        Lhm=new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Event_para>();   
        System.out.println("");   
        }
```

How to modify equals and hashcode so as to display linked hashmap.

Comment: This is just a small part of the code . Lhm is defined in the constructor if this class so no worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`equals()`, `hashCode()` and dont forget `compareTo()` are used by many container classes to compare objects. The LinkedHashMap uses them to sort them properly into the map. Java does automatically generate them. You only need to overwrite them if the default does not work properly.

They are not meant to produce any output!

You may override the `toString()` method of the object to produce output, but you also must call it somehow. E.g.

```
public class Main
{

    public static class Person
    {
        String name;
        Integer age;

        public Person(String name, Integer age)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "Person with name=" + name + " and age=" + age;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        LinkedHashMap<String, Person> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Person>();

        // fill the map
        map.put("a", new Person("Stefan", 45));
        map.put("b", new Person("Lisa", 40));
        map.put("c", new Person("Madonna", 60));

        // print the map
        System.out.println(map);

        // or iterate over the content
        for (Map.Entry<String, Person> entry : map.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "-->" + entry.getValue().toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
{a=Person with name=Stefan and age=45, b=Person with name=Lisa and age=40, c=Person with name=Madonna and age=60}
a-->Person with name=Stefan and age=45
b-->Person with name=Lisa and age=40
c-->Person with name=Madonna and age=60
```